# Calculate Weekly Snapshot From Change Events in SQL or Tableau

Tags: sql, postgresql, salesforce, greatest-n-per-group, amazon-redshift

I have a table of snapshots of a record when a record's field is changed, like this:

```
       name         |    created_date     |       value
--------------------+---------------------+----------------------
                  a | 2016-01-01 21:36:48 | 300
                  a | 2016-01-20 17:58:00 | 400
                  b | 2016-01-06 17:58:00 | 100
                  b | 2016-01-27 17:58:00 | 300
                  c | 2016-03-03 17:58:00 | 500
```

How can I use this data to get the sum of latest values on a week by week basis using the latest row for any one name.

e.g.

```
Week 1 (1/3) - 300 (a)
Week 2 (1/10) - 400 (a+b)
Week 3 (1/17) - 400 (a+b)
Week 4 (1/24) - 500 (a'+b)
Week 5 (1/31) - 700 (a+b')
Week 6 (2/7) - 700 (a+b)
Week 8 (2/14) - 700 (a+b)
...
Week 11 (3/7) - 1200 (a+b+c)
```

If I can create a table with a row showing the up-to-date entry for each record by week, then I could just calculate the sum for each week, but I'm not sure how to create such a table.

Comment: Have a look for answers in greatest-n-per-group tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ([SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b651a8/1)) should do what you're looking for.

The weeks (in this example) start from 3rd Jan and span from Sunday to Saturday. There is an example for multiple names in a week as well as multiple one name appearing multiple times.

Comment: I think this answer is almost there, but what I would like is for each week to show the sum of the latest values for each unique name. i.e. January 10 should be 600 because latest 'a' is 300 and latest 'b' is 300.

Comment: It already does that... (in the SQL Fiddle mentioned), Jan 10th shows the latest and Jan 17th gives the sum. (Note that the SQLFiddle example values are not the values as per the question)

Comment: Updated the SQLFiddle URL to give a better values to show that it does as expected (Jan 17th now has multiple values for both a and b and still totals only the latest values)

Comment: Also, Jan 10 (in the example) means Jan 10 - Jan 16

Comment: Ah, I think there's a misunderstanding. I'm for each week, I'm looking for the sum from the end of that week all the way back to the first date, e.g. in this case 1/4. The Jan 3 (*-1/9) sum is correct because on 1/4, 'a' had value of 300. The Jan 17 (*-1/23) sum is correct because 'a' had value 300 on 1/21 and 'b' had value 200 on 1/21. However, the Jan 10 (*-1/16) sum is incorrect because 'a' had value 300 on 1/4 and 'b' had a value of 300 on 1/14. However, I fixed it by just changed `w` in line 11 to '2016/1/1'::TIMESTAMP! Now, time to try to implement this in Redshift. Thanks.