# Calculate Monthly Snapshot in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to create a monthly snapshot of items and average quantities.
The goal is for every item and and end-of-month date calculate average quantities from the past year base on the date. I.E. for 2023-09-30, the average would be from 2022-09-30. And for 2023-10-31, it would be from 2022-10-31.

There is also need to remove duplicates, this is handled with `distinct`.

At the moment I am able to create it separately for each month, and I need to update the date range manually.

Current Result:

| EndOfMonth | ItemId | AvgQuantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-09-30 | 1 | 3,28571428571429 |

Needed result:

| EndOfMonth | ItemId | AvgQuantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-05-31 | 1 | 4,66666666666667 |
| 2023-06-30 | 1 | 4,28571428571429 |
| 2023-07-31 | 1 | 3,33333333333333 |
| 2023-08-31 | 1 | 3,57142857142857 |
| 2023-09-30 | 1 | 3,28571428571429 |

```sql
CREATE TABLE #TEMP (
WorkId int, ItemId int, Quantity float, WorkDate date
)

INSERT INTO #TEMP (WorkId, ItemId, Quantity, WorkDate) VALUES
(12,1,10,'2022-05-30'),
(12,1,10,'2022-06-30'),
(10,1,8,'2022-07-30'),
(10,1,8,'2022-08-30'),
(1,1,1,'2022-09-30'),
(2,1,1,'2022-10-30'),
(2,1,3,'2022-11-30'),
(2,1,3,'2022-12-30'),
(3,1,5,'2023-04-30'),
(3,1,5,'2023-05-30'),
(4,1,2,'2023-06-30'),
(4,1,2,'2023-07-30'),
(5,1,5,'2023-08-30'),
(6,1,6,'2023-09-30')
GO

WITH work as (
    select DISTINCT WorkId, ItemId, Quantity, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())-1, -1)  EndOfMonth
    FROM #TEMP
    WHERE 
    WorkDate BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())-13, -1) /*last date of 12 months ago*/ AND DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())-1, -1) /*Last date of previous month*/
    )

SELECT 
    EndOfMonth,
    ItemId,
    AVG(Quantity)
FROM work
GROUP BY EndOfMonth, ItemId
```

I have found [calculate weekly snapshot from change events in sql or tableau](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35785106/calculate-weekly-snapshot-from-change-events-in-sql-or-tableau) and [how can i calculate daily snapshots of my total sales on sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38006233/how-can-i-calculate-daily-snapshots-of-my-total-sales-on-sql) but I am not certain how to continue. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a while loop for this. Here is the SQL.

```sql
CREATE TABLE #TEMP (
WorkId int, ItemId int, Quantity decimal(18,5), WorkDate date
)

INSERT INTO #TEMP (WorkId, ItemId, Quantity, WorkDate) VALUES
(12,1,10,'2022-05-30'),
(12,1,10,'2022-06-30'),
(10,1,8,'2022-07-30'),
(10,1,8,'2022-08-30'),
(1,1,1,'2022-09-30'),
(2,1,1,'2022-10-30'),
(2,1,3,'2022-11-30'),
(2,1,3,'2022-12-30'),
(3,1,5,'2023-04-30'),
(3,1,5,'2023-05-30'),
(4,1,2,'2023-06-30'),
(4,1,2,'2023-07-30'),
(5,1,5,'2023-08-30'),
(6,1,6,'2023-09-30')
GO

DECLARE @WorkMonthlySnapshot TABLE(EndOfMonth DATE, ItemId int, Quantity decimal(18,5))
DECLARE @I INT

SET @I = 0
WHILE @I <= 12

BEGIN
    WITH work as (
    select DISTINCT WorkID, ItemId, Quantity, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())-1-@I, -1) EndOfMonth
    FROM #Temp
    WHERE 
    WorkDate BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())-13-@I, -1) /*last date of 12 months ago*/ AND DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())-1-@I, -1) /*Last date of previous month*/
    )

    INSERT INTO @WorkMonthlySnapshot(EndOfMonth, ItemId, Quantity)
    SELECT 
        EndOfMonth,
        ItemId,
        AVG(Quantity) Quantity
    FROM work
    GROUP BY EndOfMonth, ItemId

    SET @I = @I + 1
END
SELECT * FROM @WorkMonthlySnapshot
```